# What is 'Time Profile'?

Tags: macbook-pro, mojave

In System Preferences > Keyboard > Services > Development, I see options for 'Time Profile Active Application', 'Time Profile App Under Mouse', and 'Time Profile Entire System'.

What do these things do?

I've searched Google for "Time Profile" and "Time Profile Active Application", but no results show for that. Well, the later shows 4 total results on the interwebs, which none are useful in explaining what the program is.

I'm on MacBook Pro Mojave. I happened to find these options when I was adding the Finder right-click option for 'New Terminal At Folder'. After enabling all of them, I didn't see any new options related to 'Time Profile', but I do see the Terminal option.

[image]

Comment: can you post an image? It kinda sounds like a dev tool

Comment: What’s with the downvotes? +1 to offset

Comment: I've added a screenshot and more notes.

Comment: What section under Services does this fall under? For example, Add to iTunes as a Spoken Track is located under Text.

Comment: Keyboard > Shortcuts > Services > Development

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They're shortcuts for developers to start time profiling an app using Instruments, which is a developer tool that's installed alongside Xcode. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instruments_(software)